# IOS - How to get the main view of current screen

Tags: ios, swift, view, tokbox

I'm building an app where I need to share some screens with a website via tokbox,
I want to share the main global view of the app so I won't have to switch screen capturers for every viewcontroller I create.
Also, I noticed that in VCs which has camera preview it won't show up on the other end.
What can be the cause to that and how can I fix these problems?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: We have to see some code. Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. Here we like to help our fellow developers solve issues they have in current projects. Please include examples, inputs, outputs, expected results, and current results.

Comment: I would recommend joining the Vonage community slack as well - https://developer.nexmo.com/community/slack

Comment: I have a main UIWindow var in my appdelegate which I give to my ScreenCapturer and pass to the tokbox session's publisher var , CODE: "        let windowview = AppDelegate.shared().window
        if isOnline ?? false {
            if self.capturer == nil {
                self.capturer = ScreenCapturer(withView: windowview!)
                self.onlineSessionManager?.switchToScreenSharing(capturer:self.capturer!)
            }"